# How can I allow/facilitate users to upload images and create a slideshow?

Tags: views, javascript

I want the users of my page (who will not be especially technical) to be able to upload multiple images which other users can comment on etc.

I'm thinking of using the Drupal core module 'book' to create the parent page, which would display the images stored in its children.

Is it possible to do this dynamically so that the users do not have to create a new content type for each of the slideshows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you "could" use the 'Book' module with the child pages as you described. However that is not really going to help your users a lot. Except maybe from easily navigating from the images posted by 1 user to another user (if that is what you also want to consider)? And it does not really help I think for reducing the number of nodes to be created.

What I think is more important to consider are these items:

- Add an image field to the content type you are considering using, in which you allow "multiple images". That way a single user may add all their images to "their" node. And with "permissions" it's straight forward to ensure that they can only edit their "own" node (e.g. to add more images later on). And at the same time avoid they (accidently?) add "their" images to a node of another user.
- Use the [Field Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_slideshow) module to actually create a slideshow from these images.
- To further simplify (for your users) the upload process of images, you may also want to consider using the [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) module, which is an image/file uploader and browser that supports personal directories and quota.

With only these 3 items you should get pretty close to what you're looking for I think, no?

Comment: I don't think this would allow users to comment on each individual image, only the group of images

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestions and the tutorial. Very helpful and should help me get to where I want to go.